# Formatação de vários valores float não fica alinhada quando a quantidade de dígitos é diferente

Tags: python

Estou tendo problemas de formatação, devido a quantidade de dados que aparece na tela, tento inserir o `\t` porém está bugando. Segue imagem e código:

```
# Método da Falsa Posição - Cálculo Numérico
# Desenvolvido - Felipe Roque de Albuquerque Neto
# Instituto Federal de Pernambuco - Campus Recife
# Curso de Bacharelado em Engenharia Mecânica

#Importamos a biblioteca de matemática
import math 

# Definição dos intervalos [a,b]
a = float(input("Digite o valor de a: "))
b = int(input("Digite o valor de b: "))
print("\n")

# Definição da tolerancia
e = float(input("Digite o valor da tolerância desejada: "))
print("\n")

# Construção da Funçãa para entrada das equações
def f(x):
    return x**3-x-4 #Equação escolhida

print("a \t\t\t\tb   \t\t\t\tf(a)  \t\t\t\tf(b) \t\t\tXr  \t\t\t\tf(Xr)")
print("\n")
# Teoremo de Bolzano + Cálculo das iterações pelo método da Falsa posição
if(f(a)*f(b)) < 0:
    Xr = ((a*f(b))-(b*f(a)))/(f(b)-f(a))
    while(math.fabs(f(Xr)) > e):
        Xr = ((a*f(b))-(b*f(a)))/(f(b)-f(a))
        print("{} \t\t\t{} \t\t{} \t\t{} \t\t{}".format(a,b,f(a),f(b),Xr))
        if f(Xr) == 0:
            print("A raiz é: ".format(Xr))
        else:
            if f(Xr)*f(a) < 0:
                a = Xr
            else:
                b = Xr
    print("\n")
    print("Valor da raiz é: {}".format(Xr))
    print("\n")
else:
    print("Não há raiz no intervalo informado! Reveja seus dados!")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema de usar `\t` é que se o tamanho dos dados variar, de fato a sua formatação poderá ficar "torta". Uma alternativa é definir um tamanho a ser ocupado por cada informação, usando os [formatos específicos disponíveis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec).

Por exemplo, você poderia definir um tamanho específico que cada coluna ocupará e alinhar à esquerda:

```
size = 25 # cada coluna ocupará 25 espaços
print(("{:<{size}} " * 5).format("a", "b", "f(a)", "f(b)", "Xr", size=size))
...
if f(a) * f(b) < 0:
    Xr = ((a * f(b)) - (b * f(a))) / (f(b) - f(a))
    while math.fabs(f(Xr)) > e:
        Xr = ((a * f(b)) - (b * f(a))) / (f(b) - f(a))
        print(("{:<-{size}} " * 5).format(a, b, f(a), f(b), Xr, size=size))
```

O formato para o nome das colunas é `{:<{size}}`. O `<` indica que a coluna será alinhada à esquerda, e o `size` indica o tamanho da mesma (no caso, é 25).

Também fiz `"{:<{size}} " * 5` para gerar a string `"{:<{size}} {:<{size}} {:<{size}} {:<{size}} {:<{size}} "`, assim fica mais fácil mudar o formato, pois você só precisa mudá-lo uma vez. Claro que poderia também escrever assim:

```
print("{:<{size}} {:<{size}} {:<{size}} {:<{size}} {:<{size}} ".format("a", "b", "f(a)", "f(b)", "Xr", size=25))
```

Mas se precisar mudar o formato das colunas (por exemplo, se quiser alinhar à direita, tem que trocar o `<` por `>`), terá que fazê-lo 5 vezes. Então se o formato é o mesmo para todas as colunas, acho que compensa fazer da primeira forma (`"{:<{size}} " * 5`).

No caso dos números (dentro do `while`), eu também uso `-` no formato, que indica que o sinal deve ser impresso somente para números negativos. E assim como fiz para os nomes das colunas, eles ocupam 25 espaços e estão alinhados à esquerda.

A saída fica assim:

```
a                         b                         f(a)                      f(b)                      Xr                        


-2.5123456789012346       30                        -17.34528080057978        26966                     -2.491446277458697        
-2.5123456789012346       -2.491446277458697        -17.34528080057978        -16.973719545318616       -1.536716542515489        
-2.5123456789012346       -1.536716542515489        -17.34528080057978        -6.092236087424354        -1.008525001102407        
-2.5123456789012346       -1.008525001102407        -17.34528080057978        -4.017268648696145        -0.5552502296408267       
-2.5123456789012346       -0.5552502296408267       -17.34528080057978        -3.615934980583952        -0.03980470236627769      
-2.5123456789012346       -0.03980470236627769      -17.34528080057978        -3.9602583647745715       0.6917518662933995        
-2.5123456789012346       0.6917518662933995        -17.34528080057978        -4.360734317386491        1.7678170288055575        
-2.5123456789012346       1.7678170288055575        -17.34528080057978        -0.24307582649463333      1.8286515287594436        
1.8286515287594436        1.7678170288055575        0.2862977656530621        -0.24307582649463333      1.7957507916056346
```

Obviamente que se os números forem tão grandes que ocupam mais que 25 espaços, a solução seria aumentar o `size` e/ou limitar as casas decimais (que já foi comentado na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/434632/112052)).

---

#### Outra opção

A solução abaixo é apenas uma curiosidade, já que é preferível usar as opções disponíveis no `format` (veja na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) que há muitas outras opções para controlar a formatação, que é melhor do que tentar ajeitar manualmente com espaços e TABs).

De qualquer forma, é possível mudar o "tamanho" de um `\t`, usando o [método `expandtabs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.expandtabs). Então bastaria mudá-lo para um tamanho que seja suficiente para conter todos os números, evitando assim as colunas desalinhadas:

```
size = 25
print("a\tb\tf(a)\tf(b)\tXr".expandtabs(size))
...
if f(a) * f(b) < 0:
    Xr = ((a * f(b)) - (b * f(a))) / (f(b) - f(a))
    while math.fabs(f(Xr)) > e:
        Xr = ((a * f(b)) - (b * f(a))) / (f(b) - f(a))
        print(("{}\t" * 5).format(a, b, f(a), f(b), Xr).expandtabs(size))
```

Assim, cada `\t` terá o tamanho indicado (no caso, 25), e a saída fica similar ao exemplo anterior.

Mas eu ainda acho melhor usar os formatos específicos que o `format` disponibiliza, pois são mais poderosos e flexíveis, e menos propensos a erros, se comparados com uma formatação manual.

Comment: Caramba, eu não sabia da existência desse `<` no format. Muito bom a resposta, mas testando isso eu percebi que usar `<` não limita o tamanho do valor, ele só adiciona espaços se necessário. Então como faria se o valor fosse maior do que 10 por exemplo ?

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 No teste que fiz (veja a saída acima) tem valores maiores que 10 (30 e 26966). Não entendi sua pergunta... De qualquer forma, tb dá pra combinar o `<` com `.3f`, se não me engano, aí você tem um controle bem completo sobre o formato...

Comment: O que eu quero dizer é que para que tudo fica formatado, as strings precisam ter o mesmo tamanho, mas ao executar isso por exemplo `"{:<10}".format("string com o tamanho maior que 10")`, podemos ver que a string não terá o tamanho 10 porque `<` serve somente para adicionar espaços mas não limitar a string a um tamanho de 10 entende ?

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 Sim, não tem muita mágica, tem que verificar o tamanho das colunas que vc está trabalhando e escolher um tamanho adequado que sirva. O mesmo acontece se  limitarmos a quantidade de casas decimais, como dito no final da sua resposta. No fim, ambas as nossas respostas terão problemas similares, dependendo dos dados e do tamanho escolhido.

Answer (score 1):

O caractere `\t` funciona perfeitamente, o que ocorre é que os dados podem ter tamanhos diferentes e o espaçamento deve se adequar a essa diferença. O que você pode fazer aí é criar um código para definir um tamanho fixo para os dados, de forma que os espaços vazios da string sejam ocupados por caracteres de espaços (`" "`). Exemplo:

```
tamanho = 25
string = "2.343"
string_formatada = string + (" " * (tamanho - len(string)))
```

Há uma outra forma mais simples e talvez seja a melhor no seu caso que é definindo zeros depois do valor. Para fazer isso utilize dentro das chaves `:.<num>f` para acrescentar zeros depois do ponto flutuante. Veja abaixo um exemplo:

```
valor = 2.345354
string_formatada = "{:.10f}".format(valor)  # 2.3453540000
```

O problema desse tipo de formatação, é que caso o número seja maior do que o tamanho que você definiu, ele pode perder a sua precisão. Além disso, essa formatação limita os números apenas depois do ponto flutuante. Logo, se o número for `273.35` e eu limitar o valor somente pelos decimais, o tamanho final do dado pode não ser o esperado. Exemplo:

```
# No exemplo, eu quero que dado tenha um tamanho de 5 caracteres.

valor = 273.45
string_formatada = "{:.3f}".format(valor)

# O tamanho é 7 pois há 3 caracteres antes do ponto 
# quando o esperado era ter somente um caractere antes.
print(len(string_formatada))
```

Comment: hum, entendi. Irei testar essas suas dicas, obrigado!