# Como imprimo uma tabela com todas as iterações no Python?

Tags: python

Com o código abaixo eu consigo apenas as respostas finais, como faço para que imprima cada passo?

```py
def funcao_volume(x : float):
    return 4*(x**3) - 1014*(x**2) + 62370*x

def calculate_alpha(delta: float):
    numerador = delta*(5**(1/2) -1)
    return numerador/2

def calcuatex1(b : float, alph: float):
    return b - alph

def calcuatex2(a: float, alph: float):
    return a + alph

def abs(a:float, b:float):
    if a>b:
        return a - b
    else:
        return b - a

a = 0
b = 105
resp = list()
erro = 1
it = 1

#Iniciando o processo
while erro > 0.001 or len(resp) < 1000:
    delta = b - a
    alph = calculate_alpha(delta)
    x1 = calcuatex1(b,alph)
    x2 = calcuatex2(a,alph)
    v1 = funcao_volume(x1)
    v2 = funcao_volume(x2)
    if v1<=v2:
        a = x1
    else:
        b = x2
    erro = abs(a,b)
    it = it+1
    resp.append({"it": it, "erro":erro,"v1":v1,"v2":v2,"x1":x1,"x2":x2})

#printando o ultimo resultado
print (resp[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar um laço `for` para percorrer todas as respostas e imprimi-las, dessa forma:

```
for resposta in resp:
    print(resposta)
```

Nesse caso, você imprimirá cada dicionário contido na lista. Se você quiser obter os valores das respostas para formatar o que será impresso, utilize a sintaxe dos colchetes `[]` passando a chave de cada valor.

No exemplo abaixo, vou utilizar um outro `for` para percorrer cada chave do dicionário e formatar a impressão.

```
for resposta in resp:

    for chave in resposta:
        print(chave, "=", resposta[chave], end = " | ")

    print("\n")
```

Se quiser deixar a saída bem bonita com os valores separados, dê uma olha nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/434632/157404) de uma outra pergunta que fala sobre formatação em Python.

Comment: Muito obrigada!